# How to manage screen sharing settings via cli?

Tags: screen, sharing

I need to manage my ubuntu screen-sharing settings via cli (specifically via a puppet script).  How can I set up [the native screen-sharing functionaility](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/sharing-desktop.html.en) by editing a text settings file, or some other cli-friendly way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so via the dconf database, either using the `gsettings` tool or the `dconf` CLI tool directly

Ex.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino notify-on-connect false

dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/remote-access/notify-on-connect 'false'
```

As noted in the manual page,

> ```
>    Note that gsettings needs a D-Bus session bus connection to write
>    changes to the dconf database.
> ```

so additional steps (such as launching a dbus session and attaching it to an appropriate session bus) may be necessary if you are trying to do this from outside of a desktop session.